# Creating Restful API what kind of headers should be put out before the response?

Tags: php, rest, http-headers

I am not finding a whole lot of information on this, maybe I am just searching wrong, who knows.. What I want to know or try to figure out is what kind of headers should I output for API responses example

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Is something I would put out for the type of data, but are there others for time, expiration, or anything else for that matter that I should concern myself with?

Ultimately I am attempting to make an API for an app I want to develope so I am trying to figure out early what will be cross platform compliant and what needs are so I can try to build them into my idea of what would be part of standard dev

Comment: Are you asking which HTTP response headers are required? That's too broad, try reading the relevant RFCs. Why reinvent the wheel and not use a library/framework that can handle this for you?

Comment: I should say "it depents"?

Comment: `Content-type` only defines what format the data is in when you return it. There isn't any specific format an API "should" respond with. A REST-api can return JSON, XML, HTML, What ever. Many API's can even return the data in multiple formats, letting the caller decide what fits him/her best. So like @Federico says... It depends.

Comment: currently I am using codeigniter since thats what I am most familiar with, but it like most frameworks I have attempted to use in the past dont outright put headers out that would necessarily be compliant across the board for lets say a JSON response. So I am ultimately just trying to figure out what would be the bare minimum that I should expect to output other than content-type for example.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the end result is planned to have multiple formats, first run however I am going with JSON since thats more specific to my overall needs, I plan on expanding it in the future

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json` is perfectly valid and enough for saying it's JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Now this is all you want.

Primary file: `Rest.inc.php`

```
<?php
    class REST {

        public $_allow = array();
        public $_content_type = "application/json";
        public $_request = array();

        private $_method = "";        
        private $_code = 200;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->inputs();
        }

        public function get_referer(){
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        }

        public function response($data,$status){
            $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
            $this->set_headers();
            echo $data;
            exit;
        }

        private function get_status_message(){
            $status = array(
                        100 => 'Continue',  
                        101 => 'Switching Protocols',  
                        200 => 'OK',
                        201 => 'Created',  
                        202 => 'Accepted',  
                        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',  
                        204 => 'No Content',  
                        205 => 'Reset Content',  
                        206 => 'Partial Content',  
                        300 => 'Multiple Choices',  
                        301 => 'Moved Permanently',  
                        302 => 'Found',  
                        303 => 'See Other',  
                        304 => 'Not Modified',  
                        305 => 'Use Proxy',  
                        306 => '(Unused)',  
                        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',  
                        400 => 'Bad Request',  
                        401 => 'Unauthorized',  
                        402 => 'Payment Required',  
                        403 => 'Forbidden',  
                        404 => 'Not Found',  
                        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',  
                        406 => 'Not Acceptable',  
                        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',  
                        408 => 'Request Timeout',  
                        409 => 'Conflict',  
                        410 => 'Gone',  
                        411 => 'Length Required',  
                        412 => 'Precondition Failed',  
                        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',  
                        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',  
                        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',  
                        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',  
                        417 => 'Expectation Failed',  
                        500 => 'Internal Server Error',  
                        501 => 'Not Implemented',  
                        502 => 'Bad Gateway',  
                        503 => 'Service Unavailable',  
                        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',  
                        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported');
            return ($status[$this->_code])?$status[$this->_code]:$status[500];
        }

        public function get_request_method(){
            return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        }

        private function inputs(){
            switch($this->get_request_method()){
                case "POST":
                    $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_POST);
                    break;
                case "GET":
                    //break;
                case "DELETE":
                    $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_GET);
                    break;
                case "PUT":
                    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$this->_request);
                    $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($this->_request);
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->response('',406);
                    break;
            }
        }        

        private function cleanInputs($data){
            $clean_input = array();
            if(is_array($data)){
                foreach($data as $k => $v){
                    $clean_input[$k] = $this->cleanInputs($v);
                }
            }else{
                if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                    $data = trim(stripslashes($data));
                }
                $data = strip_tags($data);
                $clean_input = trim($data);
            }
            return $clean_input;
        }        

        private function set_headers(){
            header("HTTP/1.1 ".$this->_code." ".$this->get_status_message());
            header("Content-Type:".$this->_content_type);
        }
    }    
?>
```

API Functions in file `api.php`

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    require_once("Rest.inc.php");

    class API extends REST {

        public $data = "";

        const DB_SERVER = "host";
        const DB_USER = "username";
        const DB_PASSWORD = "asdfgf";
        const DB = "database name";

        private $db = NULL;

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();                // Init parent contructor
            $this->dbConnect();                    // Initiate Database connection
        }

        /*
           Database connection 
        */
        private function dbConnect(){
            $this->db = mysql_pconnect(self::DB_SERVER,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);
            if (!$this->db)
            {
              echo "Please try later.";
            }
            if($this->db)
                mysql_select_db(self::DB,$this->db);
        }

        /*
         * Public method for access api.
         * This method dynmically call the method based on the query string
         *
         */
        public function processApi(){
            $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['rquest'])));
            if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
                $this->$func();
            else
                $this->response('',400);                // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
        }

        /*************API SPACE START*******************/

        private function about(){

            if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
                $error = array('status' => 'WRONG_CALL', "msg" => "The type of call cannot be accepted by our servers.");
                $error = $this->json($error);
                $this->response($error,406);
            }
            $data = array('version' => '0.1', 'desc' => 'This API is created by Blovia Technologies Pvt. Ltd., for the public usage for accessing data about vehicles.');
            $data = $this->json($data);
            $this->response($data,200);

        }



        /*************API SPACE END*********************/

        /*
            Encode array into JSON
        */
        private function json($data){
            if(is_array($data)){
                return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            }
        }

    }

    // Initiiate Library

    $api = new API;
    $api->processApi();
?>
```

Now finally configure `.htaccess`

Create a file named `.htaccess` in the same folder where you place `api.php` and `Rest.inc.php`

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Now call your API like

```
localhost/about
```

where about is the function. You can dynamically check whether it is GET or POST inside the function, and send response text and codes as required. I have given you entirely what you want.

Considering `api.php`  and `Rest.inc.php`  are both in /, (that is what in `RewriteBase`  in `.htaccess`  file)

If you want to place the files in some other directory or folder, for example `/beta/v1/`

Change the `RewriteBase` from `/` to `/beta/v1`

Note. Place the .htaccess in the same folder.

And both the files in the same directory. The directory should be placed in the htaccess in `RewriteBase`

If you have any issues understanding the above, let me know.

Comment: What if I need to include some other .php file in this api.php? how should it be done?

Comment: for example if I need to use a php SDK in my rest api which needs require("setup.php") or require_once("setup.php")  then where should these be added in this rest api.php?  I tried adding this below require_once("Rest.inc.php"); but this doesn't work.

Comment: Please raise it as a new question, share your research, so that I could assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

One good thing that I include in my response headers is a correlation id for the request that was sent.  This allows consumers of your API to correlate a question or a potential bug with a request and allow you to look up information pertaining to that request.

This, of course, requires you to log information associated to the correlation id but it has proven to be very useful for me.