# android json getting error due to have huge objects under array why

Tags: android, json

I have huge amount of 10,000 objects in a JSON array:

- How to fetch all the records? I am getting error out of memory error and app has shutdown.
- Can I do this by grouping them?
- out of memory error ..
  error like this  Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 86 byte allocation with 66 free bytes and 66B until OOM

-WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 50.483ms for cause Alloc  I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 33MB to 32MB

This is my code for Gallery image..why this is not showing full window

public class Act_PhotoGallery extends Act_Main {

```
public static Act_PhotoGallery act_gallery;
GridView lv;
```

ImageView img_tab2,imv_logout;

```
RelativeLayout rel_tab2;
LinearLayout slidingPanel;
TextView menu1,menu2,menu3,txt_log_name;
ImageView imvslide,imv_log_pic;
String log_name,log_pic,log_id;
URL url;
Bitmap image;

public void setBackApiResponse(int requestcode, Object obj1) {

    if (requestcode == ConstantValue.REQUESTCODE_VIEWGALLERY_LIST)
        setData(obj1);

}

private void setData(Object obj1) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TeamAdapter TeamAdapter = new TeamAdapter(this,(ArrayList<View_Gallery>) obj1);
    lv.setAdapter(TeamAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            View_Gallery v=new View_Gallery();

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    log_name = preferences.getString("name", "");
    log_pic = preferences.getString("log_pic", "");
    log_id = preferences.getString("log_id", "");
    findIdsfromXML();
    initialize();
    String uri = getRequestUrl();
    if (uri != null) {
        HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper(
                ConstantValue.REQUESTCODE_VIEWGALLERY_LIST, Act_PhotoGallery.this,
                "Loading...");
        httpHelper.execute(uri);
    }
}
private void findIdfromBottomXml()
{
    img_tab2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottombar_tab2_img_gallery);

    rel_tab2=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottambar_rel_tab2);
  //  imv_logout=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv_logout);

}
private void findIdsfromXML() {

    lv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    slidingPanel=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.slidingPanel);
    menu1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_1);
    menu2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_2);
    menu3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_item_3);
    imvslide=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv_slide);
    slidingPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slidingPanel.getLayoutParams();
    slidingPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    slidingPanel.setLayoutParams(slidingPanelParameters);

    txt_log_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_title_1);
    imv_log_pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv_prof);
    String img = ConstantValue.URL_profile_photo +log_id+"/"+log_pic;
    //


    //
    if(!log_pic.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(this);
        //String img = ConstantValue.URL_profile_photo + log_id + "/" + log_pic;

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(img, null, imv_log_pic,
                60, false);
    }
    txt_log_name.setText(log_name);

    findIdfromBottomXml();
    setImagesSelectedBottom(2, rel_tab2, img_tab2);


}

private void initialize() {
    act_gallery = Act_PhotoGallery.this;

}

private String getRequestUrl() {
    String request = null;

    request = String.format(ConstantValue.URL_VIEW_GALLERY_POST);
    Log.e("Url team", request);
    return request;
}

private class TeamAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<View_Gallery> team_arrylist = new ArrayList<View_Gallery>();

    private int imgeSize = 75;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(Act_PhotoGallery.this);

    public TeamAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<View_Gallery> obj1) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.team_arrylist = obj1;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return team_arrylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        // final View_ClubList v_club= club_arrylist.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();



            holder.imgg = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

//problem found

```
        String img = ConstantValue.URL_GALLERY_IMAGE + team_arrylist.get(position).meta_value;
        if(!team_arrylist.get(position).meta_value.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(img, null, holder.imgg, imgeSize, false);
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text_teamname;
        TextView text_teamemail;
        ImageView imgg;
    }
}
public void onSlideClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imv_slide:
            slideclick(slidingPanel);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: make group of objects. Other wise use the pagination

Comment: okay thanx m trying ..

Comment: i am getting this error.. LOS objects, 0% free, 31MB/32MB, paused 1.251ms total 61.364ms
WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 54.769ms for cause Background

Comment: use the lazy loading mechanism load the data in pages or groups of 10, 20 ,.. objects

Comment: during lazy loading i will need to hit  url of every pages??thn can i hit singl e url to display whole data..
beacuse i have single webservice link for whole data.>

then what i do in this situtaion?

Comment: Your complete page is not loading  at once. make webservice like that which will provide the data in pages

Comment: i have loaded all data on app through json.org package.
but there has performance issues problem.
app hanged why??
any solutions?

Comment: App is hanged due to the heavy data & UI data binding operation so, it takes time for it. If you want more efficient way check my ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010686/how-to-deal-with-a-large-json-object-on-android/35257532#35257532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please parse all the objects from your jsonArray in a seperate Asynctask.

Comment: thanx Ryan .i have used single AsyncTask for all .now its working perfectly but takes loading time due to huge data json

Comment: @chandeshwar, first asynctask is for making webservice call and get jsonArray in onPostExecute() method of first asynctask then start your second asynctask passing jsonarray from onPostExecute() method of first asynctask and use gson for json parsing and then let me know whether the loading time is reduced or not.

Comment: nice thought ...m just trying this way..thanx bro...just trying ..updation i will tell you sure

Comment: bro..another question i am asking to you.....my gallery images showing in grid view..but when i click on any image.then..image is not coming in window size why? on same frame @ryan

Comment: @chandeshwar.. will have to look at your code buddy

Comment: Hey @Ryan ...just i have updated my Gallery code on below question on Top..please  check.i hope u see my code..buddy

Comment: Will check it today..was busy with other stuff

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` data exchanges used for light data transfer, Should you try to pass too much data as you did you will run out of memory and the network call will have to do a lot of memory management,

You may think that by requesting more heap (`android:largeHeap="true"`) might solve the problem but that is not the case,

what you can do is, request the amount of `JSON` data which you can handle at a given time and have `metadata` attached to it which will keep track of what data you got and what will you request in future.

Example:-

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "infotmation": "something to be"
    },
    {
      "infotmation": "3 AM"
    },
    {
      "infotmation": "something to be"
    },
    {
      "infotmation": "3 AM"
    }
  ],
  "metaData": {
    "currentPage": 1,
    "nextPage": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this question for large size of json object.
Please check my ans

[How to deal with a large JSON object on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010686/how-to-deal-with-a-large-json-object-on-android/35257532#35257532)