# how can approach to parse huge JSON file in android studio in android java

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to parse some huge JSON file (like [link](http://eu.battle.net/auction-data/258993a3c6b974ef3e6f22ea6f822720/auctions.json) ) using volley  library.
How can i load and add to RecyclerView.
 would like to know what is the best approch to parse this kind of big file (about 80k lines) and if you may know good API that can help me processing this.

help me ..-> Thanks.

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: use `android.util.JsonReader`

Comment: Just follow the link, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010686/how-to-deal-with-a-large-json-object-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010686/how-to-deal-with-a-large-json-object-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) just create pojo of this json for example with [Pojo generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and then just pass json to gson. [examples](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use json streaming either with `gson` or `jackson`. With `Jackson` you can use a `hybrid approach` as well. This would reduce your memory consumption significantly as only the portion of json being parsed is `loaded into memory`.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

A jackson example http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/

Comment: thaks@ Harshad.. i will try and get back  you

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Flatbuffer** library :

**- website :** https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/

**- talk 1 :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQTxMkSJ1dQ

**- talk 2 :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90ND0yQVYg8

**My advice :** By experience, Flatbuffer implementation can be complicated, so if your data can be static, use AssetManager to persist your huge JSON File in local application, and load it for use it.